# Silex Routing, how to have slashes inside route variables?

Tags: php, silex

Take this URL, for example:

`http://website.com/test/blob/my/nice/little/branch/tests/InterfaceTest.php`

In Silex, it could be expressed as a route like this (just sample code):

```
$app->get('{repo}/blob/{branch}/{tree}/', function($repo, $branch, $tree) use ($app) {
    // repo = test
    // branch = my/nice/little/branch
    // tree = tests/InterfaceTest.php
})->assert('branch', '[\w-._/]+');
```

However, this does not work as expected. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: When you say "does not work as expected", do you mean you are getting a 404 error or what exactly?

Comment: You need to allow slashes in *both* the branch and the tree parameter. Here you only allow them in branch.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$app->get('{repo}/blob/{branch}/{tree}/', function($repo, $branch, $tree) use ($app) {
     // repo = test
     // branch = my/nice/little/branch
     // tree = tests/InterfaceTest.php

})->assert('branch', '[\w\-\._/]+');
```

for more, look at this cookbook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html

Answer (score 2):

Use this, `.+` will match all remain path

```
$app->get('{repo}/blob/{branch}/{tree}', function($repo, $branch, $tree) {
    return "$repo, $branch, $tree";
})->assert('branch', '.+');
```